# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I got error in codeigniter and I dont know how to solve this. My error is:-
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/umparam.php

Line Number: 25

controller code:

```
public function edit($record_mpid)
    {
        $this->load->model('mparam');
        $record = $this->mparam->getAllRecords($record_mpid);
        $this->load->view('umparam',['record'=>$record]);
    }
}
```

Model code:

```
public function getAllRecords($record_mpid)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get_where('mparam', array('mpid'=> $record_mpid));
            if ( $query->num_rows() > 0){
                return $query->row();
            }
        }
    }
```

view code:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Parameter</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                     <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'parameter','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Parameter','value'=>set_value('parameter', $record->parameter)]); ?> // line no 25

                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <?php echo form_error('parameter'); ?>
                     </div>
                </div>
```

Please help.Thank you!!

Comment: Your error message is pretty clear at telling you what's wrong and exactly where to look.  Line 25 of your view.  However, you're not even showing us 25 lines of the view.

Comment: oh sorry. I added whole view div.now I added 25 line. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On your controller function

```
public function edit($record_mpid) {
   $this->load->model('mparam');
   $data['record'] = $this->mparam->getAllRecords($record_mpid);
   $this->load->view('umparam', $data);
}
```

Then on view

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Parameter</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<?php 
$att = array(
    'name' => 'field_name',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'placeholder' => 'Enter something',
    'value' => set_value('field_name', $record->parameter)
);

echo form_input($att);
?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<?php echo form_error('field_name', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Model

```
public function getAllRecords($record_mpid) {
    $this->db->where('mpid', $record_mpid);
    $query = $this->db->get('mparam');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row(); // will return single item;    
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but still I get the same error message.

Comment: did you load form helper in construct area and is your controller name where the first letter only upper case on file name and class.

Comment: yes I have loaded url and form helper and my controllers first letter is also in caps.

Comment: In my db file I used mysqli instead of mysql database. Is this error related to db file. If so please guide.Because I am using php7 and it doesnt support mysql db.